# Open Chrome History From Desktop

Tags: google-chrome, macros, automation, autohotkey

Using Auto Hotkey I can easily execute run google searches etc with a script like:

```
!1:: ; search google maps
InputBox, UserInput, Search Term, Search Google Maps for..., , 640, 480
if ErrorLevel
    Sleep, 10  ;
else
    Run http://maps.google.com/maps?q=%UserInput%
return
```

I am looking for a way to similarly use a hot key to open chrome history/downloads tab from outside the browser.

The issue is that it doesn't have a "URL" and is just accessed at: "chrome://history/"

Any advice.

Comment: You might wanna try out `ifWinNotActive, (chrome title)`, `run chrome.exe`, `winWait, (chrome title)`, `controlSend,, ^h, (chrome title)`. Good look with finding any solution at all, I could not

Comment: Blauhirn's comment above is going to be the best route. There is no way to open Chrome internal URLs from the command line.